# Do memory barriers guarantee a fresh read in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, volatile, memory-barriers, memory-fences

If we have the following code in C#:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;

void A() // runs in thread A
{
    a = 1;
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();
    Console.WriteLine(b);
}

void B() // runs in thread B
{
    b = 1;
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

The `MemoryBarriers` make sure that the write instruction takes place before the read. However, is it guaranteed that the write of one thread is seen by the read on the other thread? In other words, is it guaranteed that at least one thread prints `1` or both thread could print `0`?

I know that several questions exist already that are relevant to "freshness" and `MemoryBarrier` in C#, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652938/where-to-places-fences-memory-barriers-to-guarantee-a-fresh-read-committed-write/25110639?noredirect=1#comment63509441_25110639) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569274/thread-volatileread-vs-volatile-read). However, most of them deal with the write-release and read-acquire pattern. The code posted in this question, is very specific to whether a write is guaranteed to be viewed by a read on top of the fact that the instructions are kept in order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a memory fence?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286629/what-is-a-memory-fence)

Comment: @Yossarian this is not a duplicate for the reasons I explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not guaranteed to see both threads write `1`. [It only guarantees the order of read/write operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.memorybarrier.aspx) based on this rule:

> The processor executing the current thread cannot reorder instructions in such a way that memory accesses **prior to the call** to `MemoryBarrier` execute after memory accesses that **follow the call** to `MemoryBarrier`.

So this basically means that the thread for a `thread A` wouldn't use a value for the variable `b` read **before** the barrier's call. But it still cache the value if your code is something like this:

```
void A() // runs in thread A
{
    a = 1;
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();
    // b may be cached here
    // some work here
    // b is changed by other thread
    // old value of b is being written
    Console.WriteLine(b);
}
```

The race-condition bugs for a the parallel execution is very hard to reproduce, so I can't provide you a code that will definitely do the scenario above, but I suggest you to use the [`volatile` keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx) for the variables being used by different threads, as it works exactly as you want - gives you a fresh read for a variable:

```
volatile int a = 0;
volatile int b = 0;

void A() // runs in thread A
{
    a = 1;
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();
    Console.WriteLine(b);
}

void B() // runs in thread B
{
    b = 1;
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that volatile will guarantee a fresh read?  The documentation may say something similar, but having read a few articles and SO I am not so sure about that. I know that volatile disables some optimizations and issues memory barriers, but I am not so sure that it guarantees a "fresh" read like the one in this case.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that this is a guarantee as it's said in docs. Could you provide some links for this? You also can use `VolitileRead` method from Interlocked, but it is the same as marking a field as `volatile`

Comment: This link states that the memory barrier is enough  by itself:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883956.aspx
This SO question refers to volatile and freshness:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652938/where-to-places-fences-memory-barriers-to-guarantee-a-fresh-read-committed-write

Comment: As I said in answer, memory barrier is enough if your **real** code is the same as you provided in answer. But, probably, you real code contains some additional logic, and in that case memory barrier wouldn't be enough, as you've been said in comments to the linked answer.

Comment: @Petrakeas As for fresh read - I meant that the `volatile` says to the compiler not to optimize the code for this field as it can be changed by another thread. May be we have a different understanding of the `fresh` value. As you've been said in comments, in multhithreading it can be obsolete in any moment of time.

Comment: @Petrakeas More about volatile: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10589973/213550

Comment: I think that the example I provided is quite simple and tests the "freshness" in the case where a value is only changed once. I have already read the SO question in your comment. According to the accepted answer there, the volatile keyword (or even memory barriers) just restrict instruction reordering. They do not force a core to "see" the "write" of another core that may have already happened.

Comment: Yeah, so what's you're expecting as an answer? Can't see your aim right now.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. "Is it guaranteed that at least one thread prints 1?" Yes, it is. The comments in your example show that `b` might be printed as `0`; however, if that happens, it is guaranteed that `a` would then be printed as `1`. By the time `b` was cached, `a` would have been written and made visible to thread B because of the memory barrier on thread A. However, `a` could not have been read or cached yet on thread B because the memory barrier on thread B has not been reached yet (given that `b` is still 0).

Comment: I think I should reword my answer there. I was talking about two `1`, not the one. Thanks.

Comment: Apologies, I should not have assumed that. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you mean by "fresh". `Thread.MemoryBarrier` will force the first read of a variable to be obtained by loading it from its designated memory location. If that's all you mean by "fresh" and nothing more than then the answer is yes. Most programmers operate with a more rigid definition whether they realize it or not and that is where problems and confusion begin. Note that a volatile read via `volatile` and other similar mechanisms would *not* produce a "fresh" read under this definition, but would under a different definition. Continue reading to find out how.

I will use a down arrow ↓ to represent a volatile read and an up arrow ↑ to represent a volatile write. Think of the arrow head as pushing away any other reads and writes. The code that generates these memory fences is free to move around as long as no instruction goes up through a down arrow and down through an up arrow. The memory fences (the arrows), however, are locked in place at the spot where they were originally declared in the code. `Thread.MemoryBarrier` generates a full-fence barrier so it has both read-acquire and release-write semantics.

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;

void A() // runs in thread A
{
    register = 1
    a = register
    ↑   // Thread.MemoryBarrier
    ↓   // Thread.MemoryBarrier
    register = b
    jump Console.WriteLine
    use register
    return Console.WriteLine
}

void B() // runs in thread B
{
    register = 1
    b = register
    ↑   // Thread.MemoryBarrier
    ↓   // Thread.MemoryBarrier
    register = a
    jump Console.WriteLine
    use register
    return Console.WriteLine
}
```

Keep in mind that the C# lines are actually multipart instructions once they get JIT compiled and executed. I have tried to illustrate that somewhat, but in reality the invocation of `Console.WriteLine` is still going to be far more complex than shown so the time between the read of `a` or `b` and their first use could be significant relatively speaking. Because `Thread.MemoryBarrier` produces an acquire-fence the reads are not allowed to float up and past the call. So the read is "fresh" relative to the `Thread.MemoryBarrier` call. But, it could be "stale" relative to when it is actually used by the `Console.WriteLine` call.

Let us now consider what your code might look like if we replaced the `Thread.MemoryBarrier` call with the `volatile` keyword.

```
volatile int a = 0;
volatile int b = 0;

void A() // runs in thread A
{
    register = 1
    ↑              // volatile write
    a = register   
    register = b   
    ↓              // volatile read
    jump Console.WriteLine
    use register
    return Console.WriteLine
}

void B() // runs in thread B
{
    register = 1
    ↑              // volatile write
    b = register   
    register = a   
    ↓              // volatile read
    jump Console.WriteLine
    use register
    return Console.WriteLine
}
```

Can you spot the change? If you blinked then you missed it. Compare the arrangement of the arrows (memory fences) between the two blocks of code. In the first case (`Thread.MemoryBarrier`) the reads are not allowed to occur at a point in time prior to the memory barrier. But, in the second case (`volatile`) the reads can bubble up indefinitely (because there is down arrow pushing them away). In this case one can make a reasonable argument that `Thread.MemoryBarrier` can produce a "fresher" read if placed before the read than the `volatile` solution. But, can you still claim the read is "fresh"? Not really because by the time it is used by `Console.WriteLine` it might not be the latest value anymore.

So what is the point of using `volatile` you might ask. Because successive reads produce acquire-fence semantics it does guarantee that later reads produce a newer value than the previous read. Consider the following code.

```
volatile int a = 0;

void A()
{
    register = a;
    ↓               // volatile read
    Console.WriteLine(register);
    register = a;
    ↓               // volatile read
    Console.WriteLine(register);
    register = a;
    ↓               // volatile read
    Console.WriteLine(register);
}
```

Pay close attention to what can happen here. The lines `register = a` represent the read. Notice where the ↓ arrow is placed. Because it is placed after the read there is nothing preventing the actual read from floating up. It can actually float up and before the previous `Console.WriteLine` call. So in this case there is no guarantee that `Console.WriteLine` is working with the latest value of `a`. However, it is guaranteed to be working with a newer value than the last time it was called. That is its usefulness in a nutshell. That is why you see a lot of lock-free code spinning in a while loop making sure the previous read of a volatile variable is equal to the current read before assuming its intended operation is successful.

There are a couple of important points I want to make in conclusion.

- `Thread.MemoryBarrier` will guarantee that a read appearing after it will return the latest value *relative* to the barrier. But, by the time you actually make decisions or use that information it may no longer be the latest value anymore.
- `volatile` guarantees that the read will return a value that is *newer* than the previous read of the same variable. At no time does it guarantee that the value is the latest though.
- The meaning of "fresh" needs to be clearly defined, but can be different from situation to situation and developer to developer. There is no meaning that is anymore correct than anything other as long as it can be formally defined and articulated.
- It is not an absolute concept. You will find it more useful to define "fresh" in terms of being relative to something else like the generation of a memory barrier or a previous instruction. In other words, "freshness" is a relative concept like how velocities are relative to the observer in Einstein's theory of special relativity.

Comment: Brian, your arrow representation (existing in other SO questions of yours) is really helpful. "Freshness" is indeed a vague term, this is why this question is focused on this specific example. As you point out, read-acquire/write-release semantics (applied by volatile) are not enough for this example. This example requires that the store - load is not re-ordered and this is guaranteed only by a full-barrier. Some links that helped me (even though they are for C++):
http://preshing.com/20120515/memory-reordering-caught-in-the-act/
http://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/

Comment: "Thread.MemoryBarrier generates a full-fence barrier so it has both read-acquire and release-write semantics." This is not quite right, even though I understand what you mean. A Full-fence barrier is more than read-acquire and write-release. It prohibits a store - load re-order, something that is done by neither of those 2. This is why, it's implemented using a more costly processor call.

Answer (score 2):

The above answers are largely correct. However, to provide a more concise explanation to your question – "Is it guaranteed that at least one thread prints 1?" – Yes, the pair of memory barriers guarantees that.

Consider the representation below, where `---` represents a memory barrier. Instructions can be moved backward or forward, but they may not cross the barrier.

If the `A` and `B` methods are called at exactly the same time, you could get two 1s:

```
|   Thread A   |   Thread B   |
|              |              |
|    a = 1     |    b = 1     |
| ------------ | ------------ |
|    read b    |    read a    |
|              |              |
```

However, in likelihood, they will be called apart, giving a 0 and a 1:

```
|   Thread A   |   Thread B   |
|              |              |
|    a = 1     |              |
| ------------ |              |
|    read b    |              |
|              |              |
|              |    b = 1     |
|              | ------------ |
|              |    read a    |
```

Memory reordering might cause the read and/or write operations on *one* of the variables to be shifted beyond each other, again causing two 1s:

```
|   Thread A   |   Thread B   |
|              |              |
|    a = 1     |              |
| ------------ |              |
|              |    b = 1     |
|              |              |
|    read b    |              |
|              | ------------ |
|              |    read a    |
```

However, there is no way that you could get the read and/or write of *both* variables to be shifted beyond each other, since the barriers prohibit that. Therefore, it is impossible to get two 0s.

Take the second example above, where `b` has been read as 0. By the time `b` was read on thread A, `a` would already have been written as 1 and made visible to other threads, because of the memory barrier on thread A. However, `a` could not have been read or cached yet on thread B, because the memory barrier on thread B has not been reached yet, given that `b` is still 0.